Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDatabase. No matching constructor was found
Upgrade from 9.1.1 to 10.3.1
Full error:
Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDatabase. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx

Any tips on what/where to check? Thank you.

Updating the entries in web.config solved the issue. @ckhanna

SqlServerLinkDatabase has been deprecated since Sitecore version 10 and been replaced with DefaultLinkDatabase. You now to provide the link database configuration as below in Sitecore 10.3 inside Sitecore.Config file.
<LinkDatabase type="Sitecore.Links.DefaultLinkDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
    <param desc="innerLinkProviders" type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)LinkDataProviderFactory, Sitecore.Kernel" factoryMethod="CreateProvidersForAllDatabases" />
</LinkDatabase>

In Siteore 9.1, configuration for link database used to be like below in Sitecore.config file.

As an additional note,  it looks like Sitecore.config file inside your upgrade solution is the same as Sitecore 9.1.Can you replace this file that is provided with the Sitecore 10.3 download, in order to avoid these issues.
Update:
In order to resolve this issue for could not create object for DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, you will need to set resolve as true as mentioned below.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

I see. Replacing the entire Sitecore.config solved that but threw me this error: Could not load type 'Sitecore.UsedImplicitlyAttribute' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=18.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: 

]

I checked the Sitecore.Kernel dll and it's the correct version. I can't find the mentioned config entry in the solution wither.

@bonhaku you will need to add resolve=true inside the App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config file to resolve this issue. I have uploaded the image above where the same needs to be added. Let me know in case you face any issues.

The problem is that the map name="set IsAdministrator" is nowhere to be found in the solution. Any clue where to check?

@bonhaku its inside this App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config file in your inetpub folder.

Found it. But it already has resolve="true"

@bonhaku is it possible to connect over Sitecore Slack to chec the issue..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
